# dictionary component in Java

Tags: java, open-source

I am looking for an open source dictionary, The user in my application enter city name in Hebrew, and I want to translate it to English. I have another component that can use only English city names.
Where can I find such a component?

Comment: This question is primarily about the *data*, I presume.  If you don't need fancy things like fuzzy matching or suggestions, the software component itself can just be a standard `java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your main problem is not how to match Hebrew names to English ones (once you have a list of pairs), but actually how to obtain the data of matchings between Hebrew and English names. I'll also guess that you are aiming for cities in Israel if you are speaking about hebrew names. Therefore I'd try the statistics from the central bureau of statistics - they have a table with hebrew city names, and their english corressponding names. You can find it here: http://www.cbs.gov.il/ishuvim/ishuvim_print.htm

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use one of the Map implementations? For example HashMap or TreeMap? I'd even say more: just store all localized names in resource files (properties format) and use ResourceBundle to access them.

for example call your file towns.properties

```
tel-aviv = Tel Aviv
jerusalem = Jerusalem
```

The Hebrew version of your file is towns-iw.properties

```
tel-aviv = תל אביב
jerusalem = ירושלים
```

Now using ResourceBundle API create Map that contains direct associations between English and Hebrew names. Then just use it.